# How to Upload pdf File in Chrome browser from Android App

Tags: android, pdf, file-upload, mobile-website

Requirement:

Our is a mobile website in which we have a file upload control and through that file upload control we want to select a file from mobile and uploaded it to the website.

Problem:

1. When i click on file upload control it gives me two options:-

   - camera.
   - file

Screenshot:

1. Click on File Upload Control

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvWFC.png)

2. However when i go to file option for uploading the file except image files(i.e-.png,.jpg etc) all the other files get disabled because of which i am unable to click on it.

Screenshot:

- Disabled files while uploading through file upload control

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RaIzt.png)

- Enabled files while uploading through file upload control

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w41CD.png)

How to overcome this issue?

Also, i have googled a lot for it but however i was not able to get the solution

Comment: I too need to know, at least whether this is possible or not?